# How to edit the footline of the berlin beamer theme?

Tags: beamer, macros, header-footer, templates

So I tried the `\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}` and `\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{}` commands which should hide the footline if I'm right. However nothing happens when I use it.

I guess the berlin theme just doesn't handle it in the `footline`/`footnote` sections?

Edit: My initial plan was to merge the two lines at the bottom (author/title):

[image: berlin theme example]

into one, so it doesn't take as much space from the screen.

Edit 2: Here is a minimal example, in which I still get the footlines:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{berlin}
\usecolortheme{orchid}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}{bla}
    bla bla bla
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you a) make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your problem and b) add an image to describe which element you want to remove - I suspect this might be a terminological problem.

Comment: You have to make the changes after loading the theme

Comment: Oh my god... You're right, now it works. I feel dumb now :')

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! The `\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{} ` in your original question made me a bit confused :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the footline only after loading the theme, otherwise the theme will overwrite the empty footline again.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usecolortheme{orchid}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}{bla}
    bla bla bla
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]